# Python stopped working on import bs4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am getting "python.exe has stopped working" dialog box when trying to do

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Python version is:

```
2.7 (r27:82525, Jul  4 2010, 09:01:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
```

What steps can I take to investigate the root cause of this issue?

PS - I have tried re-installing beautifulsoup package but that does not solve the problem

Comment: Hard to tell. Did you try reinstalling Python?

Answer (score 0):

Might have the wrong bs4 installation. Go to this site to get your libraries if you're on Windows. http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/